# Cycles: how to get glass reflexion on precious stones

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have cytrine and blue topacio stones.
I have added glass shader material using IOR number for both stones.
I have an emission light dome.
When i render the scene my gold ring shows reflection, except my stones.
How can i get my stones with reflexion and more realistic ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those are some pretty nice render already.... :D

Comment: How did you model the rings?

Comment: Using 3Design Software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lighting glossy surfaces is always about dealing with whatever is reflected on them.
I think your setup is quite nice, but in my opinion the reflections on the glass could be brighter. I would add more contrast to the surrounding dome's texture.
On the dome you are using for lighting you might want to change the texture to the color input socket and have the intensity be a value you can control:

In this example I'm using a dome with a voronoi texture to create a somehow random pattern for the light. The curves let you control the contrast. The whole idea is to get an interesting a pattern to reflect on the glossy surfaces.

[image]

[image]