# EEVEE improve diamond and gold metal render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I want to improve my render results for diamond and gold polished metal.
Here is my screen copy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This site works best for focused questions and answers and is not meant for opinions or open ended discussions. For critique or suggestions you can use https://blenderartists.org/ there are sections for focused critique and work in progress. To understand how to make better use of this site please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center section, particularly [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51602/what-lighting-and-background-will-make-a-realistic-gemstone/51622#51622

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: use cycle rendering and JCF glass material for diamond facets with ROI : 2.42 and dispersion : 0.044.