# How can I use a python script to create a transparent, refractive gemstone?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, transparency

I have seen a few posts about rendering gemstones [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51602/what-lighting-and-background-will-make-a-realistic-gemstone?rq=1) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40226/how-to-construct-a-diamond-or-other-gemstone-material-in-cycles/40836#40836), but I need to replicate this task purely from a python script, without using the GUI at all.

Following [this example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/add-a-simple-vertex-via-python), I have managed to create a data object and attach to it a mesh built from a list of vertices.

```
import bpy
def point_cloud(ob_name, coords, edges=[], faces=[]):

    # Create new mesh and a new object
    me = bpy.data.meshes.new(ob_name + 'Mesh')
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(ob_name, me)

    # Make a mesh from a list of vertices/edges/faces
    me.from_pydata(coords, edges, faces)
    me.validate()
    # Display name and update the mesh
    ob.show_name = True
    me.update()
    return ob

# Create the object
vertices = [(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,-1,1),(-1,1,1),(-1,-1,1)]
edges = [(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(3,4)]
faces = [(0,1,2),(0,1,3),(0,2,4),(0,3,4),(1,2,4,3)]
gemstone = point_cloud('pyramid',vertices,edges,faces)
# Link object to the active collection
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(gemstone)
```

Running this creates a pyramidal object (AKA a simple gemstone) like I intend. However, the object is an opaque and grey shape without any material properties.

[image: pyramid mesh]

Now, I would like to render this object in a transparent material with a specified refractive index. Something like

```
#Pseudocode - does not actually work
gemstone.set_material(mode='Transparent', refractive_index=1.54)
gemstone.render()
```

How can I accomplish this in a python script? I see there are a few [material operations](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.material.html) in the documentation, but there are no guidelines on how to actually use them.

Related: I have never used blender before, but I am trying to learn it because I saw it had a python scripting interface. My intention is to render thousands of gemstone variations in order to identify the optimal design. I need to quickly load and render gem polyhedrons from vertex, edge, and face data (ideally less than 1s of render time per stone). I am not interested in high resolution or photorealistic effects, so I don't need to model dispersion, basic refraction is fine. If there is a package other than blender that is able to do this more effectively, then I'd also appreciate recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: This can be done. I’ll have to look a bit to see how..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+add+material

Comment: Quick and dirty example: https://pasteall.org/41FB/raw based on the linked answer. Further reading: [Control Cycles/Eevee material nodes and material properties using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-eevee-material-nodes-and-material-properties-using-python)