# Help needed to get a specific jewelry metal and diamond look in Cycles! Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a 3D model of a ring and I want to setup a scene in blender (cycles) that will give me renders exactly like this:

https://www.jamesallen.com/wedding-rings/womens-stackable/14k-white-gold-round-and-marquise-diamond-wedding-ring-item-49418

I’m having trouble getting the "glossy" blend of black, white and silver reflections on the ring. You can see my render on the top of the attached picture (with the reference render on the bottom). Any help, tips or comments would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, please share more details about settings used in materials, lighting, etc. to help others help you

Comment: The hdri  environment texture is where you get this detail, can’t reflect what isn’t present. Might take trial and error to adjust existing materials and env texture.

Comment: I think it will be easier to use a renderer that deals with caustics a bit better than Cycles. Why not try LuxCoreRender? It has seen some improvements recently and has perfect integration with Blender. It is open source and free as well.

Comment: I've added a picture of my node setup for the metal and of the scene.
I'll take a look at Lux Core, thanks.
If anyone has advice on what kind of hdri environment texture would get me this result, it would be great.
Thanks for the advice

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces/91173#91173 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30609/cycles-how-to-get-glass-reflexion-on-precious-stones/30625#30625 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51602/what-lighting-and-background-will-make-a-realistic-gemstone and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576